# kafka Partition Rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka

lets assume, A consumer group having 5 consumers, subscribes to some topic which has 10 partitions. Now if 10 more partitions are added to the same topic. It triggers re-balance. Why kafka reassigns previously assigned partitions, why it can't just assign newly created partitions among consumer group.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way Kafka partition assignors currently work, consumer rebalances are always a "stop the world" operation during which all partitions are first released from consumers before being reassigned.

That said, there is the [`StickyAssignor`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html)  which attempts to preserve the previous assignment whereas the default assignor `RangeAssignor` gives no guarantees.

To use `StickyAssignor`, set `partition.assignment.strategy` to `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor` in your Consumer configuration.

Comment: while going through StickAssignor JavaDoc TheOldRebalanceListener and TheNewRebalanceListener, it looks like still existing partitions being revoked from consumers. Although they are then being re-assigned to same consumers whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, as I said currently all assignors always revoke all partitions before re-assigning them. There is a KIP in progress to improve this situation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances) but until then StickyAssignor may be your best option